# How to get Instagram image by tags without authentication?

Tags: php, instagram-api

I was developed in my website, V.1 of Instagram API for search image by tags with URL like this:

```
 $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' . $tagName . '/media/recent?client_id=myclientid' . '&count=20';
```

That's works good  but recently not working and deprecated by Instagram. Is there any way to get that result whiteout authentication?

Comment: Is there any way to get result?ever curl solution?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is no.

As you know, Instagram recently applied more strict requirements with regard to using their APIs. Any applications that intend to use the Instagram API have to submit a request for any the scopes that they require.

```
basic - to read a user’s profile info and media

public_content - to read any public profile info and media on a user’s behalf

follower_list - to read the list of followers and followed-by users

comments - to post and delete comments on a user’s behalf

relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf

likes - to like and unlike media on a user’s behalf
```

Tags fall under the `public_content` scope. If you haven't been through the review process, it's straight forward for the most part. You provide a description of your application and how it will use the APIs. The one thing that caught me off guard when I went to submit and application for review was the requirement to submit a video showing how the scopes that you are requesting will be used.

Comment: thank, I saw that. but there isn't any third party API to do that ?

Comment: This would be also interesting for me

Comment: There may be some 3rd party API out there exposing Instagram's API, but my understanding is that this would be a violation of their client policy. The change to their API was purposed to prevent other applications from recreating the Instagram user experience and allowing users to expand the use of their data to other applications. This is apparent in the scopes and their descriptions. If you look at their policy, they describe the acceptable use cases. Assuming you have an acceptable use case, it isn't difficult to get a client approved.